# fopen not working when a variable is specified

Tags: php

im trying to get the contents of file and storing it in a file on my system, that function is working fine, when i specify the url the function is working fine, but when supply a variable which has url stored in it, it stores an empty file, meaning it failed getting the contents of the file, i have tried dozens of solutions but none is working, there is also a solution on php.net but its also not working, here is the code:

```
 $filePath = str_replace("Vary:", "", $items[13]);
//$encoding = mb_detect_encoding($filePath);
//$filePath = mb_convert_encoding($filePath, "ASCII", $encoding);
//$filePath = str_replace("?", "", $filePath);
//$filePath = addslashes($filePath);
//file_put_contents('path/'.$file_name, fopen("".$target_url."","r"));
file_put_contents('path/'.$file_name, fopen($filePath,"rb"));
```

Comment: Whats the point of the ""? There doesn't seem to be anything in between them?

Comment: I think OP is trying to remove the word `Vary:`

Comment: @Minzkraut It removes any occurrences of the string "Vary:" from the input `$items[13]`

Comment: @Coder What is the value of `$filePath` right before calling `fopen`? Does it make sense to you.

Comment: im actually talking about this part `...fopen("".$tar...`

Comment: That's commented. It makes no sense to wonder about it.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out just trimmed the variable and it worked

```
$filePath = str_replace("Vary:", "", $items[13]);
$filePath = trim($filePath);
```